# how to provide False in raw SQL query

Tags: python, django, database, django-database

I have inherited Django code that does a migration with a raw SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO karaage_projectmembership ( ..., is_project_supervisor, ...) SELECT DISTINCT ..., '0', ...
```

`is_project_supervisor` is a boolean. The full code is on [github](https://github.com/Karaage-Cluster/karaage/blob/31aac391ea4824ff8a6e32e0b88345c8acc4aabb/karaage/migrations/0006_auto_karage4.py#L594).

This works for mysql and sqlite, but [breaks with postgresql](https://travis-ci.org/Karaage-Cluster/karaage/jobs/127420207#L852):

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "is_project_supervisor" is of type boolean but expression is of type text
```

Looking in the git history, looks like in the past other values were tried but without success on *all* databases, such as `FALSE`, `0::bool`, `0`, `'f'`, `'0'`.

Is there any easy way of fixing this? Or do I need to rewrite the SQL to use the Django ORM (suspect this might be less efficient)?

This also has a [ticket on github](https://github.com/Karaage-Cluster/karaage/issues/279).

Thanks

Comment: false (no quotes please) does work on postgresql

Comment: false works with mysql too, but fails with sqlite.